# How can I add print from ArrayList in AWT?

Tags: java, arraylist, paintcomponent

I'm trying to print out the contents of my ArrayList in AWT using a for-loop. However, when i try to compile the code and run it, nothing is shown. I'm fairly new to Java, so I'm not sure what is causing this.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.time.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TimeDisplay extends Applet {
    private City WashingtonDC, Beijing, London, Tokyo, Moscow, TimeRetrieval;
    String temp;
    String []cities = {"WashingtonDC", "Beijing", "London", "Tokyo", "Moscow"};
    String [] GMT = {"-4", "+8", "+1", "+9", "+3"};
    ArrayList DisplayStrings;
    Boolean displaytype;

public void init() {
    WashingtonDC = new City("-4", "Washington D.C.");
    Beijing = new City("+8", "Beijing");
    London = new City("+1", "London");
    Tokyo = new City("+9", "Tokyo");
    Moscow = new City("+3", "Moscow");
    displaytype = false;
    DisplayStrings = new ArrayList();

    //timer
    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (displaytype = true) {
                    for (int i=0; i<GMT.length; i++) {
                        DisplayStrings.add(TimeRetrieval.GetCurrentTime12(GMT[i]).toString());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for (int i=0; i<GMT.length; i++) {
                        DisplayStrings.add(i, TimeRetrieval.GetCurrentTime(GMT[i]).toString());
                    }
                }
                repaint();
            }
        };

    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    for (int i=0; i<cities.length; i++) {
        g.drawString(Arrays.deepToString(DisplayStrings.get(i))(), 25, (i+1)*50+25);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<cities.length; i++) {
        g.drawString(cities[i], 25, (i+1)*50);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using awt? it was replaced by the (new(er) and improved Swing), and even that is quite obsolete these days. If you want to use applets, use JApplet instead, but seriously: the major browsers are stopping (if they haven't done it already) supporting applets, so you are better of with another technology

Comment: as a sidenode, `displaytype = true` doesnt just compare. just write it as `if(displaytype)`

Comment: It's part of the school curriculum, so i really have no choice but to use AWT, i know it's long out of date.

Comment: @RobertJiang Politely tell the people writing your curriculum how stupid it is to teach people outdated technology. Anyway; I would suggest: dont "print" that string directly; simply put some Label object or whatever inside your panel, and turn your list into a single string that you setText() into that label object.

Comment: learn to debug. First print length of GMT, then check if you are able to get into loop.

Comment: @RobertJiang my advice: have them change the curriculum or change courses. Normally, as soon as you end your education, something new is around the corner and you'll need to learn that to stay up to date. If starting with a technology that should've been stopped being taught 5 years ago (at least), you are at a major disadvantage as a student. 
You study and put in the time and effort, but it's pointless.